# APEX Theme does not render/appear on page

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle-apex

Oracle 12.1.0.2
Oracle APEX 5.0.3.00.03
RHEL 6.7
Tomcat 8.0.22

On application web page the theme does not appear or render.  Text, boxes, buttons do appear but the boxes for instance are transparent (i.e. white).
Works ok when Tomcat and ORDS are local to database but issue occurs when Tomcat and ORDS moved to remote server

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the fact that two separate APEX versions were installed on the same server and both environments got 'intermingled' causing some strange behavior.
Solution was to remove all APEX versions, re-install APEX version 5.0.3 and rebuild / reconfigure the ORDS web archive file.
These operations were done on the stand-alone web tier (running Tomcat 8.0) and not on the database tier which had just been upgraded to APEX 5.0.3.